# Angular4 - invalid bearer token, token= null

Tags: angular

I'm getting this error in my application written in Angular4, but I can't figure out what that does mean.

This is the stackrace:

```
content.js:92 invalid bearer token, token= null
_callee3$ @ content.js:92
tryCatch @ runtime.js:62
invoke @ runtime.js:296
prototype.(anonymous function) @ runtime.js:114
step @ content.js:218
(anonymous) @ content.js:218
Promise.then (async)
step @ content.js:218
(anonymous) @ content.js:218
(anonymous) @ content.js:218
run @ content.js:171
(anonymous) @ content.js:357
EventImpl.dispatchToListener @ VM3027 extensions::event_bindings:403
publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function) @ VM3033 extensions::utils:138
EventImpl.dispatch_ @ VM3027 extensions::event_bindings:387
EventImpl.dispatch @ VM3027 extensions::event_bindings:409
publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function) @ VM3033 extensions::utils:138
messageListener @ VM3036 extensions::messaging:240
EventImpl.dispatchToListener @ VM3027 extensions::event_bindings:403
publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function) @ VM3033 extensions::utils:138
EventImpl.dispatch_ @ VM3027 extensions::event_bindings:387
EventImpl.dispatch @ VM3027 extensions::event_bindings:409
publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function) @ VM3033 extensions::utils:138
dispatchOnMessage @ VM3036 extensions::messaging:392
```

This is an expert with the line 92 of content.js:

```
case 7:
isLogged = _context3.sent;
if (!isLogged.valid) {
  console.error('invalid bearer token, token=', localStorage.getItem('token'));
  changeIcon('unavailable');
} else {
  if (!isLogged.customerId) {
    changeIcon('unavailable');
  } else if (!isLogged.invitation) {
    changeIcon('uninvited');
  } else if (!isLogged.plan || !isLogged.plan.active) {
    changeIcon('unavailable');
  }
}
_context3.next = 15;
break;
```

The application works correctly but I have the console full of those errors.

Comment: can't you check the line which logs the console mesage  - console.error('invalid bearer token, token=', localStorage.getItem('token'));

Answer (score 1):

```
 invalid bearer token, token= null
```

This means that somewhere in the logic the Token is not being saved into localStorage.

- Check if the server is returning the Token.
- Check if the web application is receiving and storing the token correctly.
- Check if the logic to start the Authentication Process is correct.